# How do I draw a horizontal line from the third friday close of every month in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, stock

Below I have the background color of the third friday of every month and a closing line for every week. I would like to set the closing line only for the third friday. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
//Third Friday background color

study(title="sauce", shorttitle="ss", overlay=true)
c = #c2c2c2
c1 = #aa8a8a
bgColor =
    (dayofweek == friday and dayofmonth < 22 and dayofmonth > 14) ? color(c1, 90) :
    (dayofweek == friday) ? color(c, 90) :
    color(#cbcbcb, 0)
bgcolor(color=bgColor)

//Weekly close

cwl = input(true, title="Previous Closing Weekly Line")
wclose = security(tickerid, 'W', close[1]) 
wcolor2 = purple
plot(cwl and wclose? wclose :na , title="Weekly_Close",style=circles, color=wcolor2, linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (sauce)", shorttitle="ss", overlay=true)
c = #c2c2c2
c1 = #aa8a8a

//bgColor = (dayofweek == dayofweek.friday and dayofmonth < 22 and dayofmonth > 14) ? color.new(c1, 90) : (dayofweek == dayofweek.friday) ? color.new(c, 90) : color.new(#cbcbcb, 0)
bgColor = color.white
var wclose = 0.0
tmpWclose = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', close[1])

if dayofweek == dayofweek.friday and dayofmonth < 22 and dayofmonth > 14
    wclose := tmpWclose
    bgColor := color.new(c1, 90) 
else
    bgColor := color.new(#cbcbcb, 0)

bgcolor(color=bgColor)

//Weekly close
cwl = input(true, title="Previous Closing Weekly Line")
wcolor2 = color.purple
plot(cwl and wclose? wclose : na , title="Weekly_Close", style=plot.style_circles, color=wcolor2, linewidth=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to draw it interday (on daily chart)?

Comment: What is the problem? Just change the timeframe to D, everything works.

Comment: Thank you! close[1] was the problem. I changed it to close[0] and now the line seems to be at the correct price. I think it may be due to the different @version. Also changed 'W' to 'D'.

Comment: Any idea how to plot the high / low of that purple line range as well? Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the `security`, ex. for the annual high, `highW=security(syminfo.ticker, "W", highest(close,52))'.

Comment: I have an elementary problem where I keep plotting the previous periods high/low as opposed to the current.

Answer (score 0):

Translated the script to pine v4. The script works only on intraday timeframes due to `dayofweek` function behavior.

```
//@version=4
study(title="sauce", shorttitle="ss", overlay=true)
c = #c2c2c2
c1 = #aa8a8a

bool isThirdFriday = dayofweek == dayofweek.friday and dayofmonth < 22 and dayofmonth > 14

bgColor = 
  isThirdFriday ? color.new(c1, 70) : 
  dayofweek == dayofweek.friday ? color.new(c, 90) : 
  color.new(#cbcbcb, 0)
  
bgcolor(color=bgColor)

var float thirdFridayClose = na
if not isThirdFriday and nz(isThirdFriday[1])
    thirdFridayClose := close[1] // 'open' for daily timeframe

plot(thirdFridayClose)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to draw it interday (on daily chart)?